# How to switch monitor video source input by cli in Windows without third party apps?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have two PCs connected to one monitor, one VGA input and one HDMI input. [ControlMyMonitor Utility](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/set_monitor_input_source_command_line.html) could switch between input source only by SW instead of touch the HW button of monitors.

Is there a more native method without the help of 3rd party apps, like directly by `cmd` or `bat`?

Comment: ControlMyMonitor Utility supports cli commands.  The executable doesn't install anything on your system.  Writing your own version makes this needlessly complicated, and you will need to do the legwork. I would go that route.

Answer (score 0):

i'm note sure about this in your case but

1. set display source in your monitor to **auto**
2. make sure you have the **GPU Driver** installed
3. use <kbd>Win Key</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in the computer that you dont want to use and choose the last option
4. after that the display will choose the other source automatically
5. if not just go to the PC you want to use (you are not going to see anything in your monitor in this part before completing it ) and press <kbd>Win Key</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd> and press <kbd>↑</kbd> like 4 time and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

you can try step 5 first after step 2 to see if it's working without the need to step 3

Comment: If you have WIN 7 in step 5 try [Win Key]+[P] multiple times ( wait 3 seconds each time at least) until you see the display changed

Comment: thanks very much, it's an idea, by using `controlmymonitor`, i once write a `autohotkey` script to switch monitor input source by hotkeys, but still try to find someway more native...